# Using jQuery ajax to make a request to a Rails API on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, coffeescript

I have a Rails API that is working with CURL, but not with $.ajax.  Here is the controller method that makes the API:

```
  def historic_returns
    start_date = Date.new(params[:start_year].to_i, params[:start_month].to_i)
    end_date = Date.new(params[:end_year].to_i, params[:end_month].to_i)

    @result = ShillerDataMonth.records_between_two_dates(start_date, end_date)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @result }
    end
  end
```

Here is the CURL request that returns the expected output:

```
curl -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"start_year":"2008","start_month":"1","end_year":"2008","end_month":"12"}' 'http://localhost:3000/historic_returns.json'
```

Here is the CoffeeScript that is executed when a button is clicked:

```
$ = jQuery

$ ->
  $('#return_calculator_button').click ->
    $.ajax ->
      url: "http://localhost:3000/historic_returns.json"
      contentType: "application/json"
      type: "GET"
      data: {"start_year":"2008","start_month":"1","end_year":"2008","end_month":"12"}
      dataType: "json"
      success: (data) ->
        alert("success #{data}")
      error: ->
        alert("failure")
```

When the contentType header is included in the $.ajax call I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%…0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D 400 (Bad Request)
```

When the contentType header is not included in the $.ajax call I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%…0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

EDIT:
Here is the code for the #return_calculator_button

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="return_calculator_button">Calculate the Return</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: Mu is right, I had an extra -> in my CoffeeScript.  Here is the right code:

```
$ = jQuery

$ ->
  $('#return_calculator_button').click ->
    $.ajax
      url: "http://localhost:3000/historic_returns.json"
      #contentType: "application/json"
      type: "GET"
      data: {"start_year":"2008","start_month":"1","end_year":"2008","end_month":"12"}
      dataType: "json"
      success: (data) ->
        alert("success #{data}")
        console.log data
      error: ->
        alert("failure")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @muistooshort - I added the code for the #return_calculator_button element.  Thanks.

Comment: please can you put here the resultant js (the code source in the browser). I think that is a bad CoffeeScript transform issue.

Comment: @muistooshort - Thanks for the help.  I have used your answers on a bunch of other StackOverflow questions and really appreciate how much you contribute to the community :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `$.ajax` a function:

```
$.ajax ->
# -----^^
```

That function happens to return the usual options object that `$.ajax` usually gets but that's incidental. The result is that `$.ajax` thinks you're using the [`$.ajax(url, [settings])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) form rather than the usual [`$.ajax([settings])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) form. So `$.ajax` thinks that your function is a URL and that mess in your logs is the result of URL encoding a stringified function.

Drop the `->`:

```
$.ajax
  url: "http://localhost:3000/historic_returns.json"
  # as you have now...
```